# Raspberry Pi FBTFT

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm trying to install the Raspberry Pi 2.8 tft add-on (ITeadstudio). The new version of Raspbian has FBTFT drivers.

I add this line in /etc/modules
**fbtft_device name=itdb28 gpios=reset:7,dc:2,wr:3,cs:8,db00:17,db01:18,db02:27,db03:22,db04:23,db05:24,db06:25,db07:4 rotate=90**

The problem I'm facing is when the Pi boots up, it says "Failed to Start Load Kernel Modules" and the LCD still doesn't work (which was meant to make the LCD black). When I remove the line from /etc/modules, it goes away.

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: You should take a look at `dmesg` output.
PS. I know this is an old question but someone will find it when googling for their problem.